# Place Picker Null Result

Tags: flutter

I am using [Flutter Place Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/place_picker) to select a location but the results are null.

I have used the example provided but I am getting NULL result with "Unnamed Location" as per the photo below;

```
  void showPlacePicker() async {
    LocationResult result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            PlacePicker("AIzaSyBJ4Q0lFgGPr6at5IXD6j5YLAFuAKe1Nbo")));
    print(result);
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to enabling Places API, Maps SDK for Android and Maps SDK for iOS for the API key, you should also enable Geocoding API. I hope the documentation will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I had to enable Geocoding API:

[image]

Comment: Where do one find this menu

Comment: @Tinashe in this web you can see a button "Go to APIs and Services" with a direct access to the Enabled APIs section: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enable-api

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Void showPlacePicker() async {
    LocationResult result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            PlacePicker("your_api_key",
                        displayLocation: customLocation,
                        )));
    print(result);
}
```

Comment: I want to select the current gadget location and this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below and your issue will be solved:

1. In the code below press CTRL(cmd for MAC) on PlacePicker() and navigate to place_picker.dart file:

   ```
   void showPlacePicker() async {
   LocationResult result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) =>
           PlacePicker("YOUR_API_KEY")));
   print(result);
   ```

   }
2. Inside place_picker.dart file of the library replace the whole method
   `void reverseGeocodeLatLng(LatLng latLng) async{....}` with the following:

   ```
    void reverseGeocodeLatLng(LatLng latLng) async {
   try {
     final response = await http.get(
         "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?" +
             "latlng=${latLng.latitude},${latLng.longitude}&" +
             "key=${widget.apiKey}");

     if (response.statusCode != 200) {
       throw Error();
     }

     final responseJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
     print('Google maps response body ' + response.body);

     if (responseJson['results'] == null) {
       throw Error();
     }

     final result = responseJson['results'][0];

     setState(() {
       if (result['address_components'] is List &&
           result['address_components'].length >= 7) {
         this.locationResult = LocationResult()
           ..name = result['address_components'][0]['short_name']
           ..locality = result['address_components'][1]['short_name']
           ..latLng = latLng
           ..formattedAddress = result['formatted_address']
           ..placeId = result['place_id']
           ..postalCode = result['address_components'][7]['short_name']
           ..country = AddressComponent.fromJson(
               result['address_components'][6])
           ..administrativeAreaLevel1 = AddressComponent.fromJson(
               result['address_components'][5])
           ..administrativeAreaLevel2 = AddressComponent.fromJson(
               result['address_components'][4])
           ..city = AddressComponent.fromJson(result['address_components'][3])
           ..subLocalityLevel1 = AddressComponent.fromJson(
               result['address_components'][2])
           ..subLocalityLevel2 = AddressComponent.fromJson(
               result['address_components'][1]);
       }
       else {
         this.locationResult = LocationResult()
           ..latLng = latLng
           ..formattedAddress = result['formatted_address']
           ..placeId = result['place_id']
           ..name = result['address_components'][0]['short_name']
           ..locality = result['address_components'][1]['short_name']
           ..administrativeAreaLevel1 = AddressComponent.fromJson(
               result['address_components'][2])
           ..city = AddressComponent.fromJson(result['address_components'][3])
           ..country = AddressComponent.fromJson(
               result['address_components'][4]);
       }
     });
   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
   }
   ```

   }
3. Close the app. Uninstall it and Run it once again your problem will be solved.

***Note: Maps SDK for Android, Places API, and Geocoding API must be enabled for using place_picker.***

Credit: https://github.com/blackmann/locationpicker/issues/29